# Value of map from DynamoDB is undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which runs in Node.js 4.3. The input parameter of the function is a String, which is being sent from an AWS Lex bot.

I want to get an item from a DynamoDB table. In this item I have a Map-type attribute, which contains a String key and String value. I want to get a value from that map using the key String I got as a parameter at the start of the function.

The problem is that when I log the map to the console, all I see there is `{}`.

This is my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const sessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes;
const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;
const name = slots.names;

var id = null;
if (name == "a") {
    id = "00";
} else if (name == "b") {
    id = "01";
}

var params = {
    TableName: 'names',
    Key: {
        'id' : {S: 'test-id'}
    }
};

var names = {};

dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err); // an error occurred
    } else {
        names = data.Item.names.M;
    }
});

console.log(names);

var content = names[id];

callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled',
{'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': content}));
```

As you can see, there is a `console.log` line at the end of the code. This line logs just `{}`. The final message's content is `undefined`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamodb.getItem() is executing **asynchronously**, it has a callback function for this very reason.

console.log(names) is executing before any value is returned in the call to dynamodb.

Add a console.log() inside the getItem function and you will see that this is true.

Google "asynchronous javascript" and you'll find some good pointers.